# Array List C implementation

Tags: algorithm, c, array

I want to show you my implementation of the array list in C. Is there something I can improve or fix?

**Header**

```
#ifndef ARRAY_LIST_H
#define ARRAY_LIST_H

#include <stdlib.h>

static const int AL_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 16;

struct array_list {
    int *array;
    size_t capacity;
    size_t count;
};

struct array_list *al_new(void);
int al_destroy(struct array_list **list);

int al_ensure_capacity(struct array_list *list, size_t capacity);

int al_push_back(struct array_list *list, int data);
int al_pop_back(struct array_list *list, int *data);
int al_push_front(struct array_list *list, int data);
int al_pop_front(struct array_list *list, int *data);

int al_is_valid_index(struct array_list *list, int index);
int al_get(struct array_list *list, int index, int *data);
int al_set(struct array_list *list, int index, int data);

int al_insert(struct array_list *list, int index, int data);
int al_delete(struct array_list *list, int index);

int al_find(struct array_list *list, int data);
int al_find_last(struct array_list *list, int data);
int al_contains(struct array_list *list, int data);

int al_is_empty(struct array_list *list);
int al_clear(struct array_list *list);

int al_delete_first(struct array_list *list, int data);
int al_delete_last(struct array_list *list, int data);

int al_print(struct array_list *list);

#endif //ARRAY_LIST_H
```

**Source**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "array_list.h"

struct array_list *al_new(void) {
    struct array_list *list = malloc(sizeof(*list));
    if (list == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    list->array = malloc(sizeof(*(list->array)) * AL_INITIAL_CAPACITY);
    list->capacity = AL_INITIAL_CAPACITY;
    list->count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list->capacity; ++i) {
        list->array[i] = 0;
    }
    return list;
}

int al_destroy(struct array_list **list) {
    if (list == NULL || *list == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    free((*list)->array);
    (*list)->capacity = 0;
    (*list)->count = 0;
    free(*list);
    *list = NULL;
    return 0;
}

int al_ensure_capacity(struct array_list *list, size_t capacity) {
    if (list == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    size_t old_capacity = list->capacity;
    if (old_capacity < capacity) {
        list->capacity = (capacity + capacity / 2);
        list->array = realloc(list->array, sizeof(*(list->array)) * list->capacity);
        if (list->array == NULL) {
            return -1;
        }
        for (size_t i = old_capacity; i < list->capacity; ++i) {
            list->array[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int al_push_back(struct array_list *list, int data) {
    if (list == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    al_ensure_capacity(list, list->count + 1);
    list->array[list->count] = data;
    ++(list->count);
    return 0;
}

int al_pop_back(struct array_list *list, int *data) {
    if (list == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    *data = list->array[list->count - 1];
    list->array[list->count - 1] = 0;
    --(list->count);
    return 0;
}

int al_push_front(struct array_list *list, int data) {
    if (list == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    al_ensure_capacity(list, list->count + 1);
    memmove(&(list->array[1]), list->array, list->count * sizeof(*(list->array)));
    list->array[0] = data;
    ++(list->count);
    return 0;
}

int al_pop_front(struct array_list *list, int *data) {
    if (list == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (data != NULL) {
        *data = list->array[0];
    }
    memmove(list->array, list->array + 1, list->count * sizeof(*(list->array)));
    list->array[list->count] = 0;
    --(list->count);
    return 0;
}

int al_is_valid_index(struct array_list *list, int index) {
    if (list == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    return index >= 0 && index < list->count ? 0 : -1;
}

int al_get(struct array_list *list, int index, int *data) {
    if (list == NULL || !al_is_valid_index(list, index)) {
        return -1;
    }
    *data = list->array[index];
    return 0;
}

int al_set(struct array_list *list, int index, int data) {
    if (list == NULL || !al_is_valid_index(list, index)) {
        return -1;
    }
    list->array[index] = data;
    return 0;
}

int al_insert(struct array_list *list, int index, int data) {
    if (list == NULL || al_is_valid_index(list, index) < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    al_ensure_capacity(list, list->count + 1);
    memmove(&(list->array[index + 1]),
            &(list->array[index]),
            (list->count - index) * sizeof(*(list->array)));
    list->array[index] = data;
    ++(list->count);
    return 0;
}

int al_delete(struct array_list *list, int index) {
    if (list == NULL || al_is_valid_index(list, index) < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    memmove(&(list->array[index]),
            &(list->array[index + 1]),
            sizeof(*(list->array)) * list->count);
    list->array[list->count] = 0;
    --(list->count);
    return 0;
}

int al_find(struct array_list *list, int data) {
    if (list == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < list->count; ++i) {
        if (list->array[i] == data) {
            return data;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int al_find_last(struct array_list *list, int data) {
    if (list == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    for (int i = (int)list->count - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (list->array[i] == data) {
            return data;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int al_contains(struct array_list *list, int data) {
    return al_find(list, data) ? 0 : -1;
}

int al_delete_first(struct array_list *list, int data) {
    if (list == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    int index = al_find(list, data);
    if (index >= 0) {
        al_delete(list, index);
    }
    return 0;
}

int al_delete_last(struct array_list *list, int data) {
    if (list == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    int index = al_find_last(list, data);
    if (index >= 0) {
        al_delete(list, index);
    }
    return 0;
}

int al_is_empty(struct array_list *list) {
    if (list == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    return list->count == 0 ? 0 : -1;
}

int al_clear(struct array_list *list) {
    if (list == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < list->count; ++i) {
        list->array[i] = 0;
    }
    list->count = 0;
    return 0;
}

int al_print(struct array_list *list) {
    if (list == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (list->count == 0) {
        printf("list is empty\n");
        return 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < list->count; ++i) {
        printf("array list node %d: %d\n", i, list->array[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

A definitely better than average effort.

**No documentation**

`.h` file deserves overall documentation.  Consider users should be able to understand what these functions do without access to the `.c` file.

**Bug: `al_contains()`**

`al_contains()` returns 0 when `data` is not found or if `data != 0`.

Did OP want `al_contains()` to return the index when found?

**Hide it**

`struct array_list` definition not needed in .h file.  Only its declaration needed.  Research [Information hiding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding)

**Unclear return**

`al_find()` returns -1 when `data` not found, yet `-1` is a valid `data`.  Consider a different approach.

**Use `const`**

For functions that do not modify the state of the list:
Example:

```
//int al_is_valid_index(struct array_list *list, int index);
int al_is_valid_index(const struct array_list *list, int index);
```

**Include first**

In `array_list.c`,code `#include "array_list.h"` first to test that it does not rely on any `<.h>` files that it does not include itself.

**Why 10?**

Zero is a better choice for `AL_INITIAL_CAPACITY`.

Often the list are used, there are many empty ones.  Zero is a natural choice.

If concerned about a lot of initial re-allocations, simply jump use to 10 when first needed.

**Name space**

Code uses `al_...` and `array_list...`.  Use one,

**`static`??**

`static const int AL_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 16;` serves no purpose in the .h file.

**Order?**

With so many functions, consider alphabetizing the order in both `.c` and `.h`.

**Mixed indexing types**

Code using `int` and `size_t` for the array indexing and sizing type.  Suggest `size_t` throughout.

**Pedantic growth**

Insure `capacity + capacity / 2` does not overflow.

**More functions**

Consider:

A right-size function to reduce the allocation to the needed size.

With `al_find()` and `al_find_last()`, perhaps a `find_next(... index)` to pickup after `al_find()`?

Consider an *apply* function, one that applies a passed in function to every element of the array.  I'd such this is a better way to print too and delete `al_print()`.

```
int al_apply(struct array_list *list, void *state, int (*f)(void *state, size_t index, int data));
```

Consider `al_sort(int (*cmp)(const void *e1, const void *e2))`.

Comment: Perhaps suggest [Doxogen](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html) comments?

Comment: @pacmaninbw I am neutral on Doxogen.  You could post that idea though in an answer.

Comment: Is `struct al_list` a good name instead `struct array_list`?

Comment: @lester A key is uniformity  among all the functions and types for this task.  For me. `al_list` has redundant (l)ist.  Perhaps `struct al`?

Comment: What do you think about `struct al_type`?

Comment: The next thing that wonders me is what I should return from functions like `al_find` if I used `size_t` instead of `int` everywhere. Any ideas here?

Comment: @lester why do you see `al_find()` needing to return other than true and false?  Either it found `data` or not.  Are you looking to re-define the functionality of `al_find()`?

Comment: What do you think about returning true or false from `al_find` and saving the index to the argument passed as a pointer if it's not null?

Comment: @lester Good...

Answer (score 5):

This is a problem:

> ```
>         list->array = realloc(list->array, sizeof(*(list->array)) * list->capacity);
> ```

If the allocation fails, then we have overwritten `list->array` with a null pointer, leaving no way to access the memory it was pointing to.  That's a *memory leak*.  Don't overwrite any values until we know our reallocation was successful:

```
    size_t new_capacity = capacity + capacity / 2;
    int *new_mem = realloc(list->array, sizeof *list->array * new_capacity);
    if (!new_mem) { return false; }  /* using <stdbool.h> */
    list-array = new_mem;
    list->capacity = new_capacity;
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Give Your Structures More Informative Names

This is a **dequeue**, not a list.  The Java class named `ArrayList` doesn’t have `push_front` or `pop_front` operations, and these should change the underlying implementation.  It’s also not a generic container, but a dequeue of `int` values.  A user might later want a list (or dequeue) of some other type.

When I last wrote [an implementation of one of these here,](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/283362/136816) I named the type `q_int_t` and prefixed the functions manipulating it with `q_int_`.

#### Array Offsets are *Never, Ever* `int`

Right now, you have

```c
    for (int i = 0; i < list->capacity; ++i) {
        list->array[i] = 0;
    }
```

On most modern systems, `int` is a 32-bit signed value, and `size_t` is an unsigned value wider than that.  So, your `int` index could—realistically—overflow.  This is **undefined behavior**, which most compilers take as permission to break your code and insert serious bugs.  A classic example is that `3U < -1`.

Use `size_t` consistently for indices and offsets, or if you really, truly want signed values that can handle negative indices, `ptrdiff_t`.

Furthermore, if this code compiled without warning you that comparing an `int` to a `size_t` is a serious red flag, you need to turn on more compiler warnings.  On GCC, Clang or ICX, I typically use a `-std=` option plus `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wconversion -Wdeprecated`, where `-Wconversion` is what ought to enable the warning about this.

#### Consider a More Familiar Naming Scheme

If you take an existing, well-known implementation, such as the STL or the Java standard library, and give your interfaces similar names to that, it will be faster to learn.

You don’t currently do this: the name of the class is `array_list`, like Java `ArrayList` (although this is actually a dequeue rather than a list).  But your API is a mix of names similar to `Java.util.ArrayList<int>`, and others similar to the STL’s `std::dequeue<int>`.  You neither use Java’s `.add` and `.ensureCapacity` nor the STL’s `.push_back` and `.reserve`, but a mixture of both.  I expect I’d sometimes get them mixed up.

#### Make the `struct` Keyword Optional

It’s standard in C (and automatic in most derivatives) to define a `struct` with

```c
typedef struct array_list {
    int *array;
    size_t capacity;
    size_t count;
} array_list;
```

This, for example, lets `fopen` return a `FILE*` instead of a `struct FILE*`.  If you feel that it would be too ambiguous whether an `array_list` is the name of a type, a variable, or a function that lists an array, the convention is to end type names with `_t`.

#### Don’t Force Heap Allocation

Currently, the only way to initialize one of these is to call `al_new`, which returns a pointer to a heap-allocated object (or possibly `NULL`—but let’s come back to that later).  However, you might want to create one of these on the stack, inside another data structure, or in shared memory.

Since you always initialize the new object to the same constants, it would be better to have a constant initializer expression, such as, in C99:

```c
#define AL_INITIALIZER ((struct array_list){NULL, 0, 0})
```

or in c89/C++

```c
#define AL_INITIALIZER {NULL, 0, 0}
```

This lets you write code like this, regardless of how the storage is allocated:

```c
struct array_list dequeue = AL_INITIALIZER;
```

You can keep around the `al_new` function as a wrapper for a heap-allocated list, but remember, C++ has a placement `new` operator that lets you initialize an object anywhere in memory.

If you ever want variants that clone, move, or fill a new list, a good interface might be to have them return a list object, which can be on the right-hand-side of an assignment statement, such as:

```c
struct array_list copy_of_queue = al_clone(&original_queue);
```

Although, be careful: programmers coming from a higher-level language might expect that this will free any memory the object being overwritten held.  In C, any such memory will leak unless freed manually.

#### Allow `const` Objects

Currently, the interface always requires that it be able to modify the object.  The deleter even asks for a pointer to a pointer that it can modify to the modifiable object.

It’s useful (and safer) to be able to wipe the object to a valid empty state, but interfaces that could be implemented without modifying the object should take a `const struct array_list*` rather than an `array_list*`, and there should be a way to free the memory of a `const struct array_list` (even though this leaves it in an invalid state).

#### Fix Your Error Reporting

The big no-no here is having interfaces return `int`, with a magic value that could *either* be a valid result, *or* an error code, with absolutely no way to tell which it is.  If you are assuming that no list will ever contain this magic number, you never check for that, nor warn that the seemingly-legit operation `al_push_back( &some_al, -1 );` will cause logic errors.

If you genuinely want to pack both results into the same return value, one thing you could do is return a wider integral type, such as `long long int` for a container holding `int` values, `static_assert( sizeof(long long int) > sizeof(int), "" );` and `#define AL_NOT_FOUND LLONG_MIN`.  Then, `AL_NOT_FOUND` always means that the result was not found and can never be a valid result.  You could even write a wrapper to check if a result is valid (that is, between `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX`) and have more different error codes lower than `INT_MIN` than you would ever possibly need.

A somewhat more complex way would be to define an option type.  The fact that the user must unpack the type to extract the value is in some ways a benefit, since the type system will catch a bug caused by propagating an error value.

#### Don’t Report Out-of-Memory in-Band

In most real-world, practical coding (and certainly for learning projects), running out of memory is not a recoverable error.  You can’t even safely print an error message, because that might need dynamic memory.  Not only that, but the way modern 64-bit OSes work, the system will thrash to a halt long, long before it reports that it is out of virtual memory to allocate.  Or if you’ve put a limit on the memory the process can receive, you want it to halt if a memory leak reaches that point.

So, a memory allocation failing should be a fatal error, and you should write a handler that aborts the process with a human-readable error message if it happens, *and preserves the call stack for debugging*.  Maybe you really, truly are writing an app that needs to recover gracefully from exhausting all available memory.  In that case, you know what kind of data the recovery needs, and it’s probably not to pass the error code back up the stack.

Either way, the caller shouldn’t have to test the return value for an error, again, because the interfaces should only return normally if the memory operations all succeeded.

#### Check for Capacity Overflow

Currently, one memory bug you do not check for is the capacity overflowing a `size_t` value and wrapping around.  This isn’t likely to happen on a 64-bit system, but might on one where `size_t` is smaller.  Either compare to `SIZE_MAX - old_capacity`, or check that the new capacity is greater than the old.

You could try setting the capacity to the maximum possible, `SIZE_MAX/sizeof(array[0])`, instead, but needing more than `SIZE_MAX` bytes of memory is a logic error.  Most programs should report it if it happens and abort.

### Consider Zeroing Out Newly-Allocated Memory

This is very easy to do with the initial allocation: just call `calloc` instead of `malloc`.  For memory that doesn’t come from the heap, there’s `memset`.

If there are no bugs in your program, the contents of memory past the current end of your list should never matter.  If, however, there is a bug that does read them, and those values are different every time the program runs, that will be a heisenbug that is very difficult to reproduce.  If, on the other hand, you always initialize the unused elements to the same value, the contents of that memory will be deterministic and the bug will appear more consistently.

There is a trade-off, in that zeroing out a large amount of memory returned by `realloc` costs time (and might clobber your L1 cache).

#### Use Efficient Dequeue Operations

The classic way to implement a dequeue with both back and front insertion is to keep a pair of indices, for the current front and back of the array.  You `pop_front` by incrementing the front index, leaving empty space at the end of the array.  When pushing to the front, if there is such empty space, you can use it instead of shifting the entire array.  You can shift if you run out of room at the back, or when you reallocate, or if the amount of free space at the front is above a threshold (to save the library from getting locked into moving the array on every single insertion when you alternate between `pop_front` and `push_back` with the array exactly at capacity).

#### Be Consistent about What Your Return Values Mean

The search API is hopelessly broken.  You currently have both an `al_find` and `al_contains`, but both only return two possible values, and in neither case do those two possible values tell the caller whether or not the result was actually found.

Currently, you implement the contains check as

```c
int al_contains(struct array_list *list, int data) {
    return al_find(list, data) ? 0 : -1;
}
```

Where `al_find` is defined to return `-1` on failure, or the value being searched for on success.  However, in C, `0` is the falsey value and `-1` is truthy.  So, `al_contains` is **falsey** whenever you search for a value other than `0`, whether the list contains it or not.

What you actually want is for `al_find` and its backwards counterpart to return either the index of the element it found, or a pointer to it.  If not found, it should return a special value, either the invalid index `SIZE_MAX` or the invalid pointer `NULL`, and possibly given a name like `AL_NOT_FOUND`.  `AL_CONTAINS` should return a `bool` from `stdbool.h` and be implemented with `return find(list, data) != AL_NOT_FOUND;`.  Both should accept a `const struct array_list*` as their first argument, since neither needs to modify the list.

With that interface, you could iterate between two positions you searched for in the list.

#### Other Functions You Might Want to Implement

- Serialization more flexible than printing to `stdout`
- Clone a list
- Move a list
- Swap two lists
- Transform a list by calling a function on each element
- Reduce a list, especially by taking the sum
- Find the next occurrence of an element in the list after (or before) a given position
- Element-wise binary operations on two lists

Comment: Note that POSIX has reserved names ending in `_t`.

Comment: @Haris Many libraries use the `_t` naming convention for types, although POSIX rarely if ever defines containers such as this. If you want to be reasonably safe from name conflicts with other libraries, a good practice is to add a short prefix to all your identifiers, in lieu of language support for namespaces.

Comment: Also, for functions which could error but also need to return a value, a common pattern is to use an out-parameter for the actual result, and the actual return value as a success/failure indicator

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury That’s a really good point. So obvious it didn’t even occur to me to mention it, but if I’m listing more exotic solutions, I probably should.

Answer (score 1):

A few more points:

In `al_new` you could use calloc to zero `list->array` and avoid the explicit loop to do so.

I think you provide only false safety by making `al_destroy` take a pointer to the list pointer.
You have no control over how many copies of the pointer the caller is keeping, and nulling the one they pass in doesn't change any others.

Bug in `al_push_back`, `al_push_front` and `al_insert`: if al_ensure_capacity fails, you are writing to a NULL pointer.  Need to check the return value.

`al_pop_back` should check that `data` is not NULL before writing to it.

`al_is_valid_index` returns the opposite of normal C truthiness. I see that it matches the "0 means success" pattern of other functions, but this seems error prone.   Someone is going to write `if (al_is_valid_index(my_list)) { /*do stuff with index */ }`  and get surprised.

Actually, you make the mistake yourself in `al_get`, `al_set` and others.

All your `al_is...` functions seem to have the truthiness wrong.
If you are going to consistently use 0 for success, consider having functions return an `error_code` enum with named values for `SUCCESS, INVALID_ARGUMENT, NO_MEMORY` etc.

`al_is_empty` returns the same for not-empty and NULL list. I'd suggest adding different return values. If not, it makes more sense to me that a NULL list is empty.